# Get number of documents per field in MongoDB, like Studio3T Schema operation

Tags: mongodb, count, robo3t, studio3t

How do I obtain the distribution of fields among a MongoDB collection, i.e the total count of documents for each field (without knowing the fields) ?

E.g. considering these documents :

```
{ "doc": { "a": …, "b": … } }
{ "doc": { "a": …, "c": … } }
{ "doc": { "a": …, "c": …, "d": { "e": … } } }
```

I would like to get

```
{ "a": 3, "b": 1, "c": 2, "d": 1, "d.e": 1 }
```

Studio3T has a "Schema" feature which does exactly that (and a bit more) for a random sample of the DB, how is the query constructed ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [db.collection.countDocuments()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#db.collection.countDocuments) with the [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator:

```
db.collection.countDocuments({ a: { $exists: true});
db.collection.countDocuments({ b: { $exists: true});
db.collection.countDocuments({ c: { $exists: true});
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this solution is very inefficient.  Furthermore, it's impracticable when you don't know the fields in advance (I'll add this point in the question).